# angularjs: ngAnimate not working

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to angularjs. I am trying angularjs with rails (using "angularjs-rails" gem). I am having trouble using ngAnimate. The functionality works fine i.e. angular is properly installed and "addEntry" function adds up the new entry, but animation is not working. I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngAnimate'])

@MainCtrl = ($scope) ->
  $scope.entries = [{name: "Dummy1"}, {name: "Dummy2"}]

  $scope.addEntry = ->
    $scope.entries.push({name: "Dummy3"})
```

Here is the html file:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="addEntry()"></button>
  <div ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-animate="'demo'">
    <a>{{entry.name}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS to support ngAnimate:

```
.demo-enter {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  background: #000;
}

.demo-enter.demo-enter-active {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-animate` attribute is deprecated in 1.2 and no longer used. Instead, animations are now class based.

If you want your ng-repeat enter animaiton to be named 'demo' you have to decorate it with some additional classes following a special naming convention:

```
.demo.ng-enter {
  transition: all linear 500ms;
  opacity: 0;
}

.demo.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Then just put the 'demo' class on the element containing the ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries" class="demo">
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/kNeXtl6TpGNvtQEpErwh?p=preview

Good source on the subject: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fade animation, set opacity to 0 at the setup class, and opacity to 1 at the active

```
.animate-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Its not about the animation effects, the issue is that it is not supporting animations.
By the way(in my understanding), the styling that you have mentioned in the answer should work when we use ng-animate="'animate'".